# Aubtm 20 bluetooth module working

Tags: bluetooth

I am using **lemaubtm 20**. When i am connecting it with **hyperterminal** it receives OK and afterwards when i type **LLL** it also shows OK.

My problem is when i type other commands e.g **AT** it gives me **ERROR**

If anybody have any idea please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Please say more about your setup.  What environment are you working with, etc.

Comment: Please mention the ERROR which you are getting!!!

Answer (score -2):

you'e getting an " ok" response after you connect aubtm20 ..that's great you have made all ur electronic connections necessary for the pc to "talk" to your bt module..! i exactly know where you are getting it wrong .. after you connect to the command mode by pressing " LLL" before you type any command you have to follow the format : < c r >atcommand  ..you achieve that by doing the following in the hyperterminal (for winxp): ctrl+m(for < cr >)  ctrl+j (for < lf >)

tell me what you get ?

Comment: I believe the general consensus of StackOverflow is to encourage writing in complete sentences, using complete words. Short-hand is great in texts, but not here, sorry!

Comment: sorry .. it's my first post .. i appreciate the rules and will abide by them..thanks !

Comment: No worries! I came across your post exactly because it was your first: StackOverflow automatically flags first posts, encouraging more established users to comment on them.